# Styling a Label Attached to Text Inputs

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to style all labels that precede input fields, except for checkboxes and radio buttons.

Using the ~ selector I've gotten everything working except "text" input tags--every other type I try will apply the style, but the text does not, and I've been staring at it for too long.

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <label for="MyText">Text Field</label>
  <input id="MyText" type="text" /><br />

  <label for="MyUrl">Url Field</label>
  <input id="MyUrl" type="url" /><br />

  <label for="MyCheck">Checkbox</label>
  <input id="MyCheck" type="checkbox" /><br />
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
INPUT:not([type="radio"]):not([type="checkbox"]) ~ LABEL {
  width: 100px;
}

INPUT:not([type="radio"]):not([type="checkbox"]) {
  width: 200px;
}

LABEL { display: inline-block; }
```

I would like to avoid specifying the text input labels by ID or class to keep my code clean.

I have a JSFiddle for this as well: http://jsfiddle.net/buzzsurfr/GWk96/1/

EDIT: This screenshot is from JSFiddle.  I tried it using FF & Chrome.
[image: Text Input Label is not lined up with one below it (a "url")]

Comment: Both of your selectors seem to be working fine ..

Comment: I added an image of what I see in JSFiddle.  The "Text Field" label doesn't match the first CSS assignment in IE, FF, & Chrome.

Comment: The problem is that the `~` combinator doesn't select preceding elements

Comment: Why don't you just select `label`?

Comment: Even your fiddle itself does not achieve what you state you wish to achieve. The label for the checkbox IS styled. Your CSS code will add the style to all labels that loosely follow an input that is not a checkbox or a radio button. Assuming you have control over the HTML, add some classes and be done with it.

Comment: Just add a class for labels you need to style

Comment: @Blender: There are labels I don't want to style--namely the ones for checkbox and radio buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can swap `input` and `label` in the HTML, that will allow you to use `+` that means "immediately followed by" in order to apply styles. To swap them back visually you can use `float`. Something like this:

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input id="MyText" type="text" />
    <label for="MyText">Text Field</label>
    <br />
    <input id="MyUrl" type="url" />
    <label for="MyUrl">Url Field</label>
    <br />
    <input id="MyCheck" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="MyCheck">Checkbox</label>
    <br />
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
INPUT:not([type="radio"]):not([type="checkbox"]) + LABEL {
    width: 100px;
}

INPUT:not([type="radio"]):not([type="checkbox"]) {
    width: 200px;
}

LABEL { 
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

BR {
    clear: both;
}
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/G3FED/3/

More info about `+` CSS selector you can find here http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a "preceding" CSS selector, there is none as far as I know.

So, your best option, assuming you have control over the HTML and not only the CSS, is to add classes to the labels you want to style. This would be the simplest, cleanest and cross browser solution.

Now, in case you want to style all the labels in the form, except the labels that **follow** some other elements (say, checkboxes), perhaps this approach would work for you:

1. Style all labels
2. Override labels that follow checkboxes / radios

Like so:

```
label {
    width: 100px;
    background:#ccc;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label {
    background:#eee;
    display:inline;
}
```

And the mandatory [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DPvyc/3/).

Comment: This fiddle looks exactly like mine.  Can you check it?

Comment: Don't know what happened to that fiddle. I have updated the link.

Answer (score 1):

A solution for a basic Material Design type label where a placeholder is replaced by a label.

HTML

```
<div class="input-container">
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address">    
    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.input-container {
  position: relative;
}

.input-container > label {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: .5em;
  top: -1.2em;
  font-size: smaller;  
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
}

.input-container > input:not(:placeholder-shown) + label {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

You can add the attribute 'type' selectors to exclude input types. I.E: checkbox or radio

```
input:not(:placeholder-shown):not([type="radio"]):not([type="checkbox"]) + label
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working as it should
Your label attached to the text input is not targeted becouse there is not an input tag as preceding element

This code you are using:

```
INPUT:not([type="radio"]):not([type="checkbox"]) ~ LABEL {
  width:300px;
}
```

**says:**

Target all labels that are preceded by an input AND THIS INPUT etc,etc
As there is not input preceding the text label it will not be targeted

Note: I suppose you are targeting the label.,,,,,

Answer (score 0):

If you can change your **naming convention** for your `id` attribute of each `input`, for example:

- input type="text": `txtSomething`
- input type="checkbox": `chkSomething`
- input type="radio": `optSomething` etc.

Then your `label` will become:

```
<form>
  <label for="txtMyText">Text Field</label>
  <input id="txtMyText" type="text" /><br />

  <label for="txtMyUrl">Url Field</label>
  <input id="txtMyUrl" type="url" /><br />

  <label for="chkMyCheck">Checkbox</label>
  <input id="chkMyCheck" type="checkbox" /><br />
</form>
```

As such, you can use `Regular Expression` for your `CSS Selector` like this without swapping your `label` with `input` and `float` it:

```
label[for^="txt"] {
    width: 100px;
}
```

More about [CSS Attribute Selectors here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp).